# Facebook JSON data emojis not showing up properly?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, emoji, unicode-escapes

After many hours checking questions and answers on the stackoverflow, I couldn't get this to work. Here's the problem, consider the following JSON object from Facebook's downloadable JSON data:

```json
{
    "sender_name": "megalo\u00e5\u00bd\u00a9",
    "timestamp_ms": 1679173611981,
    "content": "Reacted \u00f0\u009f\u00a4\u008d to your message "
}
```

***The problem***: In the example JSON above, the sender name contains Japanese characters, and the chat message content contains a white heart, represented by the UTF-8 `unicode escape sequence` which is `\u00f0\u009f\u00a4\u008d`. However, when displayed on Android's TextView or Jetpack Compose, it displays as this `ð¤` which are clearly two separate characters. Android failed to interpret the whole 4-part sequence as one entire emoji.

***What didn't work***: Reading the actual JSON with UTF-8 did not do it. Android will fail to understand that there is literally one emoji and not two unicode letters. Here's the parsing logic, a JSON read directly from a json file.

`val actualJson = String(jsonInputStream.readBytes(), Charsets.UTF_8)`

Why is Android not reading the UTF-8 content correctly ?

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: your stream should contain `\u5f69` instead of `\u00e5\u00bd\u00a9` for `彩` (U+5F69,  *CJK Ideograph*) and (either) `\ud83e\udd0d` or `\U0001f90d` instead of `\u00f0\u009f\u00a4\u008d` for  `` (U+1F90D, *WHITE HEART (0xd83e,0xdd0d)*). An example (*in Python for its universal intelligibility*): you get something like `print( json.dumps( '"彩 "'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'latin1')))` (returns `"\"\u00e5\u00bd\u00a9 \u00f0\u009f\u00a4\u008d\""`) instead of `print( json.dumps( '"彩 "'))` (returns `"\"\u5f69 \ud83e\udd0d\""`).

Comment: @JosefZ Facebook bundled their JSONs this way. If I encode their JSON files' byte stream directly into Latin1 then the problem persists. If I encode their byte stream into UTF-8, decode it again as if it is Latin1 then back again to UTF-8, the problem is gone and the mojibake is solved. I wonder if it's a mistake on Facebook's part or JVM's fault, I have no idea what's in play here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround to solving this was kind of hacky. To make sure Android encodes Latin-1 characters first then leave the UTF-8 for last, I had to convert the string to a bytearray while considering it a Latin-1 string not UTF-8, but then decoding it back to UTF-8. I am not exactly sure why this worked but it's the only thing that did and I am glad it did since I was about to drop the whole thing completely after wasting hours looking for answers.

```kotlin
val finalString = String(initialString.toByteArray(Charsets.ISO_8859_1), Charsets.UTF_8)
```

This actually did the trick. No other solution worked not even the commons text's `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava/unescapeJava` methods.